# Complement of a hypersurface in a projective space

Tags: cv.complex-variables

When does the complement of a hypersurface in a projective space admit a nonconstant holomorphic function?

Comment: This should have probably been reflected towards math.stachexchange.com or another similar site...

Answer (score 7):

Always. If $H=Z(f)$ with $\deg f=d$, then $\dfrac gf$ is a non-constant holomorphic function on $\mathbb P^n\setminus H$ for any homogenous $g\neq \lambda\cdot f$ of $\deg g=d$.